# Redirect all asp.net errors to one page preferably through IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to remove all logging and tracing errors on a company website without having to run through and change all of the debugging ="true" statements (several hundred). We will refactor these later however, today, I am looking for a way to push all asp related errors to simple error page or even make everything a 404 error.

Is this possible or am I going to have to change all debug values?

relevant environment info:

.net framework 2.0, iis 7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [customErrors section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) of the web.config to push all errors to a default error page. Something along the lines of:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```